# I want to use Selenium's send keys() via a textInput variable defined in the build function of kivy framework in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, kivy

```
 def build(self):
    screen = Screen()
    type = TextInput(text="Enter job domain",pos = (270,380),size_hint =(.3, .1))
    btn = Button(text="Job Search",size_hint =(.2, .2), pos =(300, 250),background_color =(0, 0, 1, 1),)
    btn.bind(on_press=self.callback)
    screen.add_widget(type)
    screen.add_widget(btn)
    return screen

 def callback(self, event):
     driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
     driver.get('https://indeed.com')
     search_job = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text-input-what"]')
     search_job.send_keys(['data science'])
     initial_search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='whatWhereFormId']/div[3]/button")
     initial_search_button.click()
```

Here I want to use the text from the type variable initialized with a textInput variable in the def build(self) function and use it in the def callback(self,event) function in the search_job.send_keys(['']) part

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `text` from a `TextInput`, just save a reference to that `TextInput` (perhaps call it `self.type`):

```
 def build(self):
    screen = Screen()
    self.type = TextInput(text="Enter job domain",pos = (270,380),size_hint =(.3, .1))
    btn = Button(text="Job Search",size_hint =(.2, .2), pos =(300, 250),background_color =(0, 0, 1, 1),)
    btn.bind(on_press=self.callback)
    screen.add_widget(self.type)
    screen.add_widget(btn)
    return screen
```

Then use that reference wherever you need it:

```
 def callback(self, event):
     driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
     driver.get('https://indeed.com')
     search_job = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="text-input-what"]')
     search_job.send_keys([self.type.text])
     initial_search_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='whatWhereFormId']/div[3]/button")
     initial_search_button.click()
```

Comment: Thank you. This really helped me to solve the issue!